# Automatically adjusted date range in an Excel tables header row

Tags: excel, date, range, vba

I would like to have a header row for my table in Excel consisting a date range (each month a column). The date range's beginning and end should be automatically adjusted according to the figures in the table.

[image]

These figures are taken from another table via `SUMIFS` functions (one of the criteria is of course the date in the heather row). There aren't data for every month, but basically, I would like to have an output table which has starting month (first month when a figure occurs) and ending month (last month when a figure occurs) automatically adjusted. And I want to see the months without figures (between the two extremes) too. Date range cannot be taken from the other table. Any idea how to plan this?

Comment: what do you mean "figures in the table"?

Comment: Ah, I mean "figures taken from other table"

Comment: you mean values?

Comment: yes, values, exactly

Comment: I think it could be achieved with formulas, calculate minimal period in first one and then add one month to each cell to the right until you reach calculated maximum

Comment: just added a snip to the post [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V7NK.png)

Comment: I think it is a Little more complicated than that. If you look at the link, the first column supposed to be removed and a last column should be indeed the last one, because there is a value in the 7th row in that column. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, now I see what you meant, VBA needed here. I would iterate through columns from the left, deleting those having sum = 0, then repeat it from right. Both way stopping when sum != 0.

Comment: I really think you need to edit this question to show the sample data and an example of how you want the table(?) to look. At the moment your comments are refining the question, which makes it very hard to understand your question. If you could post anything you've tried so far it would also help. Try and move your links up to the question too as that will make it easier for us.